# What is the smartest way to change functional interfaces method name?

Tags: java, inheritance, functional-programming, functional-interface

Somehow I have some requirements to use all benefit of pre-written default methods and change the abstract method(`apply(T t)`) from Java `Function<T, R>`.

If I choose to make new `@FunctionalInterface` extends `Function<T, R>`, and the method name will be `operate(T t)`, I guess my code will be like below,

```java
@FucntionalInterface
public interface CustomOperator<T, R> extends Function<T, R>{

  R operate(T t);
  
  @override
  default R apply(T t){
    //do something
  } 
}
```

Let's say all of the client codes which use `CustomeOperator` only call `operate(T t)`, and if I want the interface to have all the same benefits that the default methods of `Function<T ,R>` already provide, What is the best approach for filling in the "`//do something`" parts?

of I want to know whether inheritance is not the smartest(or possible) way for my requirement or not.

Comment: `return operate(t);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code to fill the `//do something` space is rather easy: you delegate to your abstract method:

```
@Override
default R apply(T t) {
    return this.operate(t);
}
```

The ugly part is all that you need to be aware of and all that you need to keep in mind (all because `Function`'s contract is still going to be visible to your clients):

- Sub-interfaces and implementing classes of `CustomOperator` **can** override `apply`, and you can't make it final.
- You'll have to override all those `default` methods from functions, like this one:

  ```
  @Override
  default <V> CustomOperator<V, R> 
              compose(Function<? super V, ? extends T> before) {

       Objects.requireNonNull(before); //validation to replicate
       return (V v) -> apply(before.apply(v)); //or operate()
  }
  ```

  And this, you need to do because your callers work with `CustomOperator`, which of course doesn't feature on the inherited `Function.compose`, for example.
- When `java.util.function.Function<T, R>` evolves (and evolve it shall), you'll need to keep up.

The above challenges are more a question for your requirements. Why would you need to do that? It's possible, but there's maintenance work coming with it.

---

And, since you already need to override all `default` methods from `Function`, here's a good question to ask: **why not** just break the problematic inheritance? You can copy the contract but leave `CustomOperator` independent of `Function`.

Comment: Actually that was my main concern. to let the client code only use newly named methods, the overhead for overriding default methods are too high, and as you mentioned, there always will be the chance of misuse.

I guess sometimes copy and paste is not the worst choice.

Comment: True. I don't quite see that overriding is too demanding, it's just once-off development work after all... The worst part imo is mainly the unnecessary potential for confusion as well as the possibility of misuse in sub-types.

Answer (score 0):

There is only one reasonable implementation:

```
@Override
default R apply(T t) {
  return operate(t);
}
```

...and it's perfectly normal to do it that way.